# Is there a way to ask a context in EF how big its tracking set is?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm running into what appears to be a fairly typical problem in EF.  As I continue accessing my context, the number of items it tracks and enumerates over in detect changes increases.  Eventually, everything slows to a crawl.  Here's what I'm currently doing to address the problem:

```
public class ContextGenerator
{
    private IContext _context;
    private string _connString;
    private int accessCount;

    public ContextGenerator(string conn)
    {
        _connString = conn;
    }

    public IContext Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (accessCount > 100)
            {
                Dispose();
            }
            if (_context == null)
            {
                var conn = EntityConfigurationContext.EntityConnection(_connString);
                _context = new MyDbContext(conn);
                accessCount = 0;
            }
            ++accessCount;

            return _context;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _context.Dispose();
        _context = null;
    }
}
```

This mostly works to prevent my context from getting too unwieldy, as it disposes and creates a new one every 100 accesses, but it seems very clunky and messy.  Furthermore, 100 was chosen arbitrarily and there's no guarantee that somebody won't insert a million things with only one access.  Is there a way to instead ask the context itself if it's gotten "too big"?

Or if anyone has a better idea for tackling this problem, I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each context should be a single Unit of Work, therefore I would highly recommend you have 1 context per operation (unless you relly have to).

For more info on what EF is currently tracking checkout `Context.ChangeTracker`